# MSSQL: SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0) após carregar 1000 linhas

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Possuo alguns relatórios em que preciso realizar novas consultas SQL no loop. Estes relatórios estão rodando em PHP e datatables.

Em alguns momentos, quando o número de linhas atinge um volume superior a 1000, o erro ***MSSQL: SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)*** é exibido, abortando a execução do código.

Função de conexão:

```
 function pdo_mysql($sql){

    f_log($sql);

    $host = ***;
    $user = ***;
    $pass = ***;
    $db   = ***;

    try {
        $PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db, $user, $pass );
    }
    catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        echo 'Erro ao conectar com o MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage(); exit;
    }

    $result = $PDO->query( $sql );

    if (is_array($result)){
        $row = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    }else{
        $row = $result;
    }

    return $row;

 }
```

Modelo do arquivo que apresenta problema:

```
$sql = "SELECT ....";
$return = pdo_mssql($sql);

foreach ($return as $row){

    $sql2 = "SELECT ...."
    $return = pdomssql($sql2);

    foreach ($return2 as $row2){
        // Guarda dados em variáveis.
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT ...."
    $return = pdomssql($sql2);

    foreach ($return2 as $row2){
        // Guarda dados em variáveis.
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT ...."
    $return = pdomssql($sql2);

    foreach ($return2 as $row2){
        // Guarda dados em variáveis.
    }

    // Exibe resultados

}
```

Alguém já passou por algo parecido ou possui alguma sugestão?

Obrigado

Comment: Coloca o código.

Comment: Só para teste, faça sua consulta com top, `SELECT TOP 300 * FROM ... ` veja se acontece o erro. Precisa trazer todos os registros?

Comment: É só exemplo ou vc realmente tem 3 foreach dentro de um outro executando a mesma consulta?

Comment: Quando a consulta retorna menos linhas ou possui um TOP 900 por exemplo, o erro não é exibido.

Já relacionado aos foreach, possuo 10 deles dentro deste loop... Infelizmente preciso mantê-los.

Comment: A cada volta do foreach externo essas 10 consultas são re/executadas, é muita coisa, acho que precisa repensar isso.

Comment: Mas não temos restrição quanto ao tempo de execução. O problema é a interrupção do código... Mesmo sendo muita coisa, o laço não deveria seguir rodando até o final?